# Why tangent vectors rotate 720 degrees after stereographic projection from the sphere?

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, manifolds

Am reading Essential Topology by Martin Crossley.

On page 115 there is a proof for the Hairy Ball Theorem.

One part doesn't make sense.

When we apply stereographic projection to the vector field on the unit sphere it is said that this has the effect of turning the circle of perimeter inside out. The arrows or vectors rotate 720 degrees as we pass the circle.

Why it is so?

Comment: The Euler characteristic of the sphere $\chi(S^2)=2$ has to be the sum of the indices of a vector field.  If you choose a vector field with no zero at the north pole then the zero somewhere else e.g., the south pole would have to be 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little hard to be certain, but it sounds as if the author is describing the effect of lifting the Cartesian coordinate vector field $v(x, y) = (1, 0)$ to the sphere by stereographic projection. In the diagram, the dark gray circles are the images of horizontal lines $y = y_{0}$; the lighter circles are images of vertical lines $x = x_{0}$; the push-forward of the vector field $v$ is blue. Near the point at infinity, this non-vanishing vector field has a zero of index $2$:

[image: Lifting a Cartesian coordinate field to the sphere by stereographic projection]

[image: Animation: Projecting a vector to the sphere]

Comment: Can you please draw a picture showing that how one tangent vector to the unit sphere is in correspondence with a vector tangent to the unit disc via stereographic projection? This will better help me imagine why the 720 degrees rotation occurs.

Comment: The animation shows the constant vector $(1, 0)$ with its tail moving on a circle slightly outside the unit circle, and the image tangent to the sphere of the push-forward. (The tail of the vector on the sphere is the image of the tail of the vector in the plane under inverse stereographic projection from the north pole. Approximately, the head of the arrow on the sphere is the image of the head of the arrow in the plane.)

Comment: [+1] Fantastic images. Which software did you use ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Just happened across your kind comment while searching for images of stereographic projection. (I was off-site from 2017-2021.) I used [ePiX](https://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/software/ePiX.html).