# Integral Curve of the Pushfoward of A Stereographic Projection

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, vector-fields

> Let $n=(0,0,1)$ and $s=(0,0,-1)$ and let
> $\phi:\mathbb S^2\setminus\{n\}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\psi:\mathbb S^2\setminus\{s\}\to\mathbb{R}^2$
> be the stereographic projections given by $(u,v)=\phi(x,y,z)=\big({x\over 1-z}, {y\over 1-z}\big)$
> and $(r,s)=\psi(x,y,z)=\big({x\over 1+z}, {y\over 1+z}\big)$.
> Suppose that $X$ is a smooth vector field on $\mathbb S^2$ with  $(\phi_*X)(u,v)=(1,0)$ for all $(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.
>
> 1. Find the vector field $(\psi_*X)(r,s)$.
> 2. For each $(c,d)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, find the integral curve of $\psi_*X$ at $(c,d)$, that is find the smooth map $\beta:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$
>    such that $\beta(0)=(c,d)$ and $\beta'(t)=(\psi_*X)(\beta(t))$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$.

For part (1), I calculated the vector field of the pushforward to be
\begin{align*}
        \psi_* X(r, s)
        & = \left( \frac{s^2-r^2}{\left(r^2+s^2\right)^2},-\frac{2 r s}{\left(r^2+s^2\right)^2}\right)
    \end{align*}
I am not sure if my calculation is correct for part (1). But assuming it does, then for part (2). It seems like that I would need to solve an partial differential equation?

I have no prior experience on solving PDEs and I have no clue on what to do.

Any hints are appreciated!

The definition I am using is:

> Let $M\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth regular submanifold, and let $X$ be a smooth vector field on $M$.
> An **integral curve** of $X$ on $M$ at $p$ is a smooth map $\gamma:J\subseteq\mathbb{R}\to M$ with $\gamma(0)=p$
> (where $J$ is an open interval with $0\in J$) such that
> $$\gamma'(t)= X(\gamma(t))\ \hbox{ for all }\ t\in J.$$
> Let  $\sigma:U_\sigma\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m\to V_\sigma\subseteq M$ be a chart at $p$ with $\sigma(a)=p$.
> Let $\alpha:I\subseteq\mathbb{R}\to U_\sigma\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$ be a smooth map with $\alpha(0)=a$,
> and let $\gamma(t)=\sigma(\alpha(t))$.
> Let $A_\sigma$ be the smooth vector field on $U_\sigma$ such that $X(\sigma(u))= D\sigma(u) A_\sigma(u)$ for all $u\in U_\sigma$.
> Note that $\gamma'(t)=D\sigma(\alpha(t))\alpha'(t)$ and that $X(\gamma(t))=X(\sigma(\alpha(t)))= D\sigma(\alpha(t))\, A_\sigma(\alpha(t))$.

I suppose my question is similar to this question: [Why tangent vectors rotate 720 degrees after stereographic projection from the sphere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336694/why-tangent-vectors-rotate-720-degrees-after-stereographic-projection-from-the-s)

I tried to graph the vector field of the pushforward. And it looks like this?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your pushforward looks plausible up to scalar multiplication (both algebraically, and geometrically from your plot), but on algebraic grounds should be a polynomial vector field, and on geometric grounds should have a zero at the origin rather than a pole of order two. (The constant vector field $(1, 0)$ fixes the point at infinity in the Riemann sphere.)

Finding flow lines generally entails only solving an ODE, but here it's a coupled, non-linear system. The sneaky trick is, you can write down the flow of the constant vector field $(1, 0)$ by inspection; composing with $\psi \circ \phi^{-1}$ gives the flow of the pushforward vector field "because chain rule".